# Jython 3 stable version

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, jython

What is the latest stable version of Jython? I prefer a new version hopefully v3.x

- Is it still recommended to use [Jython 2.7.0 Final Released (May 2015)](http://www.jython.org/)
- What is [Jython 3 sandbox](https://github.com/jython/jython3)? Is this a official/recommended one?
- In [Wikipedia it says about v.2.7.1 released in July 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jython). Where can I download this version? (if this is the recommended latest one)

Answer (score 3):

Use [this link](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/python/jython-installer/2.7.1/) to download the 2.7.1 version:

You should definitely NOT use the newcomers which aren't stable for production purposes. You can follow [guys from their dev team](http://fwierzbicki.blogspot.rs/) for all info regarding releases.

Comment: Thanks for that. The one you shared seems a beta version. I found the correct one with the help of this one, though.  (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/python/jython-installer/2.7.1/).

Comment: Pardon, fixed it.